# How to create a UNIX timestamp for every minute in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to create a UNIX timestamp for the date `2014-10-31` for every minute of the day. I have got a timestamp for the date but not for every minute -

```
import datetime
date = '2014-10-31'
t_stamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))
print t_stamp
```

I want to save all these entries in a file which I need to access later to get specific entries only.

If I need to access one of the timestamp records using a date and specific time, how can it be done? For example, I need to find the entries for `2014-31-10` for the time between `20:00` and `20:05`, how can it be done?

Any help would be appreciated!

Updated:

```
import datetime
import ipaddress
from random import randint

for x in ip_range.hosts():

    for h in range(24): #24 hours
        for i in range(60): # 60 minutes
            f.write(str(t_stamp)+'\t'+str(x)+'\t0\t'+str(randint(0,100))+'%\n')
            f.write(str(t_stamp)+'\t'+str(x)+'\t1\t'+str(randint(0,100))+'%\n')

            t_stamp += 60 # one minute
```

Now I am looking to create a log file for every minute. How can that be done?

Comment: Sounds like you want a database more than a file, considering there are `1440` minutes in 24 hours, making all the timestamps should be pretty easy using that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I want to save server logs based on timestamps, IP addresses and server usages.
I am not sure of the syntax how to do it for every minute. Could you help me with that?

Comment: If you are going to be doing this over a long period then I would look into using sqlite or mysql, why do you need the timestamps all created?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No it's just a one-time thing, need to generate logs once and find a few instances based on timestamps.

Comment: if you want to find out where a date/timestamp lands, you can keep an ordered list of datetimes/timestamps and bisect

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have added the updated code. How can I create a log file for every minute?

Comment: `with open("{}.log".format(t_stamp),"w") as f`, can you add a sample of what you want to achieve as I don't quite follow the need for so many timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t_stamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))
for h in range(24): 24 hours
    for i in range(60): # 60 minutes
        print t_stamp
        t_stamp += 60 # one minute
```

Comment: Or `for i in range(24*60)` ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to create a new log file for every minute? Is that a good practice?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

*Storing timestamps in a database is simply redundant unless the required values cannot be corelated i.e. billing transactions' time. Here, your required range values have a start and end time, and you know them. You also know the interval between each value is 1 minute.*

```
import datetime

tvalue = datetime.datetime(2014,10,31,0,0).timestamp()  #yy mm dd 0 0

startval = ((REQD_HOUR)*3600 + (REQD_MIN)*60) #required start time

endval = ((REQD_HOUR_E)*3600 + (REQD_MIN_E)*60) # range end time

while (endval > startval):
 print(tvalue+startval)
 startval+=60
```